# DocuSign API Adding TemplateRoles to a ServerTemplate/CompositeTemplate

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to develop the following workflow in DocuSign:

There are two documents to be signed. The first is a template with 4 signatures required by 4 roles. The second document is uploaded, docx or pdf, and will be signed after the first document is complete.In the first document the first two signers need to be provided to the template and I could make this work when all I had in the envelope was the template document. After converting this to a compositeTemplate I don't see a place to add the roles to the template document. I am also unsure how to add the signature to the second document to the workflow for the template document.

The following is the json I am generating:

```
{
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "EMAIL1",
      "roleName": "ROLE1",
      "name": "NAME1"
    },
    {
      "email": "EMAIL2",
      "roleName": "ROLE2",
      "name": "NAME2"
    }
  ],
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "TEMPLATE-ID"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "documents": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "name": "Contract",
              "documentBase64": <DOC DATA>
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "[DocuSign C# SDK] - Sample Signature Request"
}
```

The template roles aren't picked up by the servertemplate and the documents are sent to the third person in the workflow.

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use multiple composite templates to add a new document.

The templateRoles specified at the root level are ignored when your envelope definition contains composite templates. The templateRoles have to be spcified within the inlineTemplate.

The tabs can be added in the second composite template.

```
{
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "templateId": "<Specify the serverTemplateId here>"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "name": "NAME1",
                                "email": "EMAIL1",
                                "roleName": "ROLE1",
                                "recipientId": "1"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "NAME2",
                                "email": "EMAIL2",
                                "roleName": "ROLE2",
                                "recipientId": "2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "2",
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "name": "NAME1",
                                "email": "EMAIL1",
                                "roleName": "ROLE1",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "signHereTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": "2",
                                            "pageNumber": "1",
                                            "xPosition": "50",
                                            "yPosition": "50"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "document": {
                "documentId": "2",
                "name": "DocumentName",
                "fileExtension": "docx",
                "documentBase64": "<Specify document bytes here>"
            }
        }

    ],
    "emailSubject": "[DocuSign C# SDK] - Sample Signature Request",
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly the piece i was missing!